How to bevel a corner without overlapping?
I'm trying to bevel this edge, but near the corners of the object the faces immediately start overlapping. I don't want to clamp overlap as this barely lets me bevel at all. Is there a way I can achieve a bevel without the faces overlapping each other like this? How are such corners dealt with?





You could delete some edges, you have  bit of a crowded spot there. And you could also use a subdivision modifier

Take a look at either of these answers and see if they help Answer1 Answer2.

@Emir thanks, spacing out the edges worked like a charm. had to dissolve some faces and fill them back in as larger ones to make space.

You could try connecting the two upper vertices with a new edge, which would solve the warping issue on the left side. It looks like the bevel is lost when the left edge just ends and the connected edge is vertical.

Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and required steps. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can, [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how it works, perhaps add a few images illustrating some steps and final result. See How to write a good answer?, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Thanks, this helped a ton. I filled in the vertices to combine the side faces together making bigger faces, helping to space out the edges and reduce overlap.
